# Remove bottom spacing on 100% width SVG graphic

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg box with a preset viewport. I want to display it so that it goes 100% across. But what is happening is that it is adding space below. How can I get rid of this?  I would rather not have to modify the viewport and inner component sizes (they are generated from some other tool which requires these) but I can add/modify attributes of the svg tag (such as the aspect ratio).   I have made a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/2MLwx/1/ - I would like the red border to be 2px all around the black box. I've tried a few variations of preserveAspectRatio but so far no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
.frame {
    margin:100px 100px 0 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
  .wrapper {
     border:1px solid red;
    padding:2px;
  }
  svg {

  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 800 150" width="100%" version="1.1">
        <rect transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000" stroke="#000"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
      Hello
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Zeaklous Im not trying to add a red border - merely have on to show the issue with spacing. Adding more svg paths will not fix this issue.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarificaton

Comment: IMO it's a bug in Chrome. FF does the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript you can change the dimensions of the svg element to the viewbox:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var width = parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[2], 10);
var height = parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[3], 10);

a.style.width = width + 'px';
a.style.height = height + 'px';

// You have to update the parent's dimensions too or else it has no idea its
// child changed dimensions
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('frame')[0];
b.style.width = (width + 2) + 'px'; // Hard coded values based on your padding
c.style.width = (width + 4) + 'px'; // Hard coded values based on your padding
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2MLwx/2/)

If your viewbox didn't start at `0,0` you could find the width by subtracting the start values like this:

```
var width = parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[2], 10) 
  - parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[0], 10);
var height = parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[3], 10) 
  - parseInt(a.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/\s+/)[1], 10);
```

If you want to include padding for the width dynamically (not sure why you'd have changing padding, but that's not my problem) it is more complex, but it'd look something like this

```
var containerPadding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(containerVar, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'), 10) 
+  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(containerVar, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right'), 10);
```

**EDIT**

I now know what you're not understanding: Your problem is due to the CSS only. You never set a width/height for the wrapper or frame, so they try to use all of the window minus the margins you have. The wrappers cannot resize itself based on the svg's height/width unless you have it change from your default values

In that case I'd just use CSS to set the necessary dimensions to the frame & container like you suggested. I originally thought you were in need of dynamically changing the dimensions

Comment: Thanks for all the code. I'd rather avoid modifying the viewport (I can set the height of my wrapper based on the ratio as well - I want to know why there is so much space below. I don't see anything in my svg that says to add ~300px of white space under it.

Comment: if it was CSS only I should be able to have text right after the svg - say just under if it's a block element. But it's not possible.

Comment: But it *is* right after the svg. The svg is taking up all of that space currently, it doesn't matter what size rectangle you  have within the svg http://jsfiddle.net/2MLwx/4/

Comment: Ah yes you are right! So it appears that an SVG without CSS or any viewport/preserveAspectRatio attribs will take over the entire page?  I guess that is what I want to prevent. It seems that hardcoding the height is the only way - which in a responsive scenario means JS

Comment: I believe if you want it to dynamically shape it to the viewbox then you have to use javascript like I did, yes

Comment: You might - I have to work on another project and will address this in a few days. I'll def reply/mark as valid

Comment: Did I end up answering your question?

Comment: I assume so. I haven't had the time to check.